# how to write this function the scala way?

Tags: scala

Consider this situation, I have a bunch of services that all need to check the input and handle errors.

```
val log = Logger("access")

def service1(){input=> 
    try{ 
        val id = input.split(",")(0).toInt
        val value = input.split(",")(1)
        //do something
    } catch {
        case e1: NumberFormatException => log.info("number format is wrong")
        case e2: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException=> log.info("not enough arguments")
    }
}
```

I want to write a method that handles this common part for every service. I could do it this way:

```
def common(input:String, log:Logger, action:(Int)=>String):String={
    try{ 
        val id = input.split(",")(0).toInt
        val value = input.split(",")(1)
        action(id)
    } catch {
        case e1: NumberFormatException => log.info("number format is wrong")
        case e2: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException=> log.info("not enough arguments")
    }
}
```

Then the service function looks like this:

```
def service1(){input=> common(input, log, id=>{
         //do something return a string
    })
}
```

Is there a way to skip the parameters in common so that it looks more elegant like map in collections?

```
common(id=>{ //... })
```

Comment: use them as tuple or make case class to achieve what you are asking for. it maybe be one of scala way though it's not functional programming way.If you are looking for functional programming way, you need to start over from the beginning.(like use scalaz/cats Either instead of String). plus your code doesn't work if your call back throws an exception other than `NumberFormatException` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.StrictLogging


class MyService extends AbstractService {
  def service1(input: String): String = common(input) {
    id =>
      id.toString
  }

  def service2(input: String): String = common(input) {
    id =>
      id.toString.toLowerCase
  }
}

trait AbstractService extends StrictLogging {

  def common(input: String)(f: Int => String): String = {
    try {
      val id = input.split(",")(0).toInt
      f(id)
    } catch {
      case e1: NumberFormatException =>
        logger.error("number format is wrong",e1)
        "" //???
      case e2: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException =>
        logger.error("not enough arguments",e2)
        "" //???
    }
  }
}
```

If input is specific you have to put it as input. Otherwise define method `def input:String` in trait and provide implementation in service.